# Silverlight Bing Maps Change mode to Aerial with Labels

Tags: bing-maps, mode

Does anyone knows how to change the view in bing maps for silverlight to Aerial with Label?

```
<m:Map Name="myMap" Grid.Row="0" Mode="Aerial">
```

Tried at lot but nothing worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

```
<m:Map Name="myMap" Grid.Row="0" Mode="AerialWithLabels">
```